# Can't find minting transaction performed in Truffle

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

When running an ERC721 mint transaction in Matic's Mumbai testnet, I get a transaction address.

However, I'm not able to view this transaction. Did it happen?

```
truffle(develop)>  instance.mint(accounts[0], 'https://ipfs.io/ipfs/Qmd9MCGtdVz2miNumBHDbvj8bigSgTwnr4SbyH6DNnpWdt?filename=1-PUG.json')

{   tx: '0x5eb16f6627ce7c827e33b58d8171c0be33992155abdf0db43f688677c39d5616',  
receipt: {
    transactionHash: '0x5eb16f6627ce7c827e33b58d8171c0be33992155abdf0db43f688677c39d5616',
    transactionIndex: 0,
    blockHash: '0x33d49e2bebc505241d03d3818ab0bb78446e915d317724b0636399c2b629a903',
    blockNumber: 3,
    from: '0x53496208528877b81d48e58fc3c669bb905ecc77',
    to: '0x242cf7ed99e0aef8980678d0bd034808d22c77fd',
    gasUsed: 23140,
    cumulativeGasUsed: 23140,
    contractAddress: null,
    logs: [],
    status: true,
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    rawLogs: []   },   logs: [] }
```

Page not found: https://explorer-mumbai.maticvigil.com/search?q=0x5eb16f6627ce7c827e33b58d8171c0be33992155abdf0db43f688677c39d5616

Comment: It seems the transaction was sent, but not on the Mumbai testnet. Can you check whether the `instance` contract was deployed on the public testnet (and not your local network such as Ganache)?

Comment: The instance contract was deployed to Mumbai. Here are the list of transactions from my test wallet. https://explorer-mumbai.maticvigil.com/address/0x830048a3Bf228569d11F9b3A1ed0D274a953b26F/transactions